# Which is most used Error Control mechanism at DataLink Layer?

Tags: networking, error-correction, error-detection, data-link-layer

I had read 3 error control techniques i.e Stop and Wait ARQ, Go Back N ARQ and Selective ARQ 
All I wanted to know which technique is currently being used in networking industry...

Can someone give me any links to get updated on current changes in 
networking industry..

Thanks

Comment: You won't find any OSI in the real world.

Comment: Your examples are from the Transport, not Data-Link, layer. Mostly, Data-Link protocols will detect an error with a CRC and simply drop the frame.